# Mongdb insert data in a collection from another collection using Node.js Api

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm new in MongoDB and NodeJS. I want to do an aggregate from another collection using NodeJS.

The thing is I have collection name `test1` There I have some field like `rcptid, rcptdate, ammount` etc.

Now I have to insert data another collection `test2` `rcptdate,totalamount` sum of amount from `test1` collection.

The SQL query like this:

```
Insert into teste(rcptdate, totalamount) values(Select 
     recptdate,Sum(amount) from test1 group by recptdate);
```

How can I make this in NodeJS? Please help Me thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest to go through the [MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/).
For your specific problem check [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) and [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/)

**A.** If your date is not biased with time then you can use below aggregation:

```
db.getCollection('tests').aggregate([{
  $group : {
    _id : "$rcptdate",
    "totalAmmount" : {
      "$sum" : "$ammount"
    }
  }
}]);
```

*Output:*

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ISODate("2018-10-24T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "totalAmmount" : 3
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ISODate("2018-10-23T10:00:00.000Z"),
    "totalAmmount" : 10
}
```

**B.** If you want date by `day of the month` then use below aggregation:

```
db.getCollection('tests').aggregate([{
  $group : {
    _id : { 
      "day" : {"$dayOfMonth" : "$rcptdate"}
    },
    "totalAmmount" : {
      "$sum" : "$ammount"
    }
  }
}])
```

*Output:*

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "day" : 24
    },
    "totalAmmount" : 3
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "day" : 23
    },
    "totalAmmount" : 16
}
```

---

And, how you can achieve in NodeJS using [mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/) library.

```
let pipeline = [{
  $group : {
    _id : "$rcptdate",
   "totalAmmount" : {
     "$sum" : "$ammount"
   }
 }
}];

test1Model.aggregate(pipeline) // Get data from here
  .allowDiskUse(true)
  .exec(function(err, data) {
    if(err || !data || !data[0]){
      Logger.error("Error ");
    } else{
      let tempObj = data[0];
      var test2 = new Test2Model(tempObj);
      test2.save(function(error, data) { // Insert data to next DB
        callback(error, data);
      });
    }
  });
```

Comment: Just an addition to your pipeline. To achieve the "insert data another collection" requirement, you could add an $out stage

Comment: Brother Where I put the url like "router.get('/acchead/particularname',function(req,res){
    acchead.find({parent:10700000}).then(function(acchead){
        res.send({"Acchead":acchead});
    })
});" this is get mine will be put

Comment: Brother Where I put the url like "router.get('/acchead/particularname',function(req,res){
    acchead.find({parent:10700000}).then(function(acchead){
        res.send({"Acchead":acchead});
    })
});" this is get mine will be post